# How do I write png file using Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I get this error message:

> WriteBlob Failed `online/images/main3.png' @
>   error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1715

```
<?php
     try{
            $image = new Imagick();
            $image->readImage("online/images/main.png");
            $image->setImageFormat("png");
            $image->writeImage("online/images/main3.png");
            header("Content-type: image/png");
            echo $image->getImageBlob();
         }
     catch(Exception $e){echo $e->getMessage();}
?>
```

> Note:- File permission set to 777

Comment: Should there be a `/` at the beginning of the path in `writeImage('/online/images/main3.png')`

Comment: my bad I will remove it .. but the problem is still the same

Comment: Other answers seem to indicate that the folder permissions need to be set as well rather than just the file permissions.

Comment: I did that, set the permission to online and images folders to 777 but I still get the same error .. I'm using centos 7, php 5.6 and Imagick latest version.

Comment: The owner of the file and folders is 'apache' do I need to change them  or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Don't use 777 permissions, that's just begging for security problems. Do you really need to write this image if you're just returning it to the user? Have you set the folder context to `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`?

Comment: Yes, I do some modification and return the new file to the user. How do I set the folder context to httpd_sys_rw_content_t?

Comment: @miken32 thank you a lot you are a life saver ... I did some search about what you said and everything is working fine. :D